# Can you reference types that are in the same interface that is being defined

Tags: typescript

Something like..

```js
type ObjectWithA = { a: number };

interface SomeObject {
   o1: ObjectWithA ;
   o2: keyof this.o1  // Obviously this does not work, but I just written it to explain. 
}
```

Actual typeof "property o1" will not be known at interface creation time but it will need to extend ObjectWithA type. And I cannot use a generic since I don't want to tell it the typeof my class, I just need it to understand it.

```js
// I don't want to do this
interface SomeObject<T extends ObjectWithA> {
   o1: T;
   o2: keyof T
```

Example usage:

```js
const obj = {
   a: 2,
   b: "string"
}

const someObject: SomeObject = {
   o1: obj,
   o2: "a" // Okay
}
const someObject: SomeObject = {
   o1: obj,
   o2: "b" // Okay
}
const someObject: SomeObject = {
   o1: obj,
   o2: "c" // Gets mad
}
```

**Edit:** I don't want generics even with a helper function for inference

Comment: You pretty much have to use generics, even though you say "I don't want to do this".  If you're concerned about having to manually specify the type argument, you can get the compiler to infer it for you by using a helper function instead of a type annotation, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/ND2a4W).  So instead of `const x: SomeObject = {...}`, you write `const x = someObjct({...})` to much the same effect. If that fully addresses your question I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (If you reply, please mention @jcalz to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, but I knew about this functionality before. That's why I thought there might be a way of doing it without manually specifying the type.

Comment: Since there isn't a better way, what do you want to see here? You could [edit] the question to clarify that you don't want generics even with a helper function for inference, and then the answer to the question would be "no, you can't" along with possibly links to feature requests for existential types (e.g., `type SomeObject = <exists T extends ObjectWithA>{ o1: T; o2: keyof T}`, not valid TS) or type argument inference for generic types (e.g., `type SomeObject<T extends ObjectWithA = infer> = {o1: T; o2: keyof T}`, also not valid TS) which would help.